# Azure AD B2C skip login page after authenticated with social logon

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have set up Azure AD B2C using custom policy that supports two identity providers:

1. Local account (email signInNames)
2. Azure AD

This means in the login page, user would be able to choose to login with Local account or click the Azure AD login button.

Let say I have 2 portals using this B2C login, Portal A & Portal B. The problem that I have right now is when a User goes to Portal A and choose Azure AD login, they will able to login fine. But when the User goes to Portal B, instead of being logged in straight away to the portal, they are presented with the B2C login page instead and have to click the Azure AD login button again. Am I missing something here? Can the user skip the login page since he has chosen Azure AD logon before (few minutes ago before the token/session timeout)?

What I have done is configure the custom policy based on the starter pack sample. If it helps, here is the excerpt from this sign in user journey:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignInOrSignUp">
  <OrchestrationSteps>   
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureAdTenantExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AzureAdTenantExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="login-AzureAD" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
     <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <!--<ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />-->
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social-NoInput" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
          <Value>AzureADAuthentication</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />    
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

-- Update 22-July-2018 --
Here is `login-AzureAD` technical profile with sensitive info `<renamed>`:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="login-AzureAD">
      <DisplayName>Azure AD Login</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your <renamed></Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.windows.net/<renamed>.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/<renamed>/</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">c5ca1fc8-05ad-4be4-b7b1-77de430e1099</Item>
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">c5ca1fc8-05ad-4be4-b7b1-77de430e1099</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_<renamed>"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="AzureADAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="<renamed>" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" PartnerClaimType="groups"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Thanks to this update request from @Chris Padgett, I noticed the error which is the session technical profile referenced `SM-Noop`. After I've changed to `SM-SocialLogin` (based on sample from others), it seems to be working now. FYI, the technical profile was created following the guide from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom).

@Chris Padgett, is this what you're looking for? I'd appreciate some explanation on this if this were correct and accept it as answer. Might help others too.

Comment: Can you please include the **login-AzureAD** technical profile as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement` element of your **login-AzureAD** technical profile must refer to the **SM-SocialLogin** SSO session provider in order to suppress the identity provider selection step:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="login-AzureAD">
  ...
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

This doesn't bypass the SSO session that might be held by the authenticated user with the external identity provider. It only remembers that an SSO session might be held by this user with this identity provider.

See [the "Azure AD B2C: Single sign-on (SSO) session management" article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sso-custom) for information about the SSO session providers.